# How to set up SQL Server listener in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I've been trying to figure out how to set up a listener on a database table from my C# code. I've been trying most recently to set up a `SqlDependency`, but I've gotten stuck because the database I'm trying to apply the procedure on is read-only and I don't have the permissions to change that (yet).

Does anyone know of other ways to go about setting something like this up? My overall goal is to allow my application to listen to a database and be notified when there is an INSERT, UPDATE, etc. and to provide specifically what was changed (i.e. which row).

EDIT: I don't have access to the code which inserts / updates the database, all that I have is read-only access to the database itself.

Comment: Cant' you track it from the code which is inserting to the db ?

Comment: Ah, no.. I have a very odd situation in which I don't have access to that part of the code (would be nice, right?) ALL that I have access to is read-only rights to the database that gets inserted into..

Comment: What is the latency requirement? Do you need to know straight away or are you just trying to capture detailed history of changes to understand what is going on. Inserting a change trigger into a table that subsequently communicates with an outside process can cause issues with database operation. The best approach might be to just turn on CDC for the table and then every change is tracked with minimal impact, and you can interrogate that afterwards. Can you post the exact version of SQL Server?

Comment: Reading up on `SQlDependency`, it seems like this might do what you want but just be aware of performance impacts. If there are suddenly 100,000 changes in one batch, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set up a [`SqlDependency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) and subscribe to the [`OnChangeEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.onchangeeventhandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). See the [example from learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency):

```cs
void Initialization()
{
    // Create a dependency connection.
    SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, queueName);
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.

    // Create a new SqlCommand object.
    using (SqlCommand command=new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT ShipperID, CompanyName, Phone FROM dbo.Shippers",
        connection))
    {

        // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
        SqlDependency dependency=new SqlDependency(command);
        // Maintain the reference in a class member.

        // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
        dependency.OnChange+=new
           OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

        // Execute the command.
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Process the DataReader.
        }
    }
}

// Handler method
void OnDependencyChange(object sender,
   SqlNotificationEventArgs e )
{
  // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).
}

void Termination()
{
    // Release the dependency.
    SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString, queueName);
}
```